# Unable to change menu settings on openbox/Lubuntu 11.04

Tags: openbox, lubuntu

I am using Lubuntu 11.04 (which I installed from Ubuntu). I tried editing menu.xml in ~/.config/openbox, and also tried using ObMenu. But Lubuntu continues to load the default settings with right click. Rebooting or re-logging in does not help. I see that the menu.xml file has changed and there are new entries.

I would like to create a rich right-click menu (also, if possible, application-specific right-click menu).

Comment: Meanwhile I have found a solution. Maybe useful to others. <code> cp
/usr/share/lubuntu/openbox/rc.xml ~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml
</code> and <code> cp /usr/share/lubuntu/openbox/menu.xml
~/.config/openbox/menu.xml </code>. Then edit the files for your desired
settings. The important part is to edit the line in lubuntu-rc.xml that
tells which menu.xml is to be used. The default is
<code><file>/usr/share/lubuntu/openbox/menu.xml</file></code>. Change it
to your local menu.xml.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work by editing the `/etc/xdg/openbox/menu.xml` file. Why there are so many `menu.xml` files around I don't know but this is the one that worked for me.